# c++ generic storage and retrieval of objects using string handle

Tags: c++, object, design-patterns, handler, handle

What would be the elegant and simple way (if exists) to implement a storage of generic objects (all other objects inherit from base). Once the object is stored, use a string handle to retrieve object or copy into another.

```
class Object{
    public:
        Object(){};
        ~Object(){};
};

class ObjectHandler{
    public:
        ObjectHandler(){};
        ~ObjectHandler(){};
        void InsertObject(std::string handle, std::shared_ptr<Object> obj){
            // some things happen before inserting
            _obj.insert(std::make_pair(handle,obj));
        }
        std::shared_ptr<Object> RetrieveObject(std::string handle){
            // some things happen before retrieving
            return _obj[handle];
        }
    private:
        std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Object>> _obj;

}
```

For example, user defined classes are

```
class Dog : public Object{
    public:
        Dog(){};
        Dog(std::string name){dogName=name};
        ~Dog(){};
        std::string dogName;
        //...
}

class Cat : public Object{
    public:
        Cat(){};
        Cat(std::string name){catName=name};
        ~Cat(){};
        std::string catName;
        //...
}
```

And the following code is executed

```
void main(){
    ObjectHandler oh;
    Cat c("kitten"), cc;
    Dog d("doggy"), dd;

    oh.InsertObject("cat#1",c);
    oh.InsertObject("dog#1",d);

    cc = oh.RetrieveObject("cat#1");
    dd = oh.RetrieveObject("dog#1");

    std::cout << cc.catName << std::endl; // expect to print 'kitten'
    std::cout << dd.dogName << std::endl; // expect to print 'doggy'
}
```

I believe there should be some well established idea (pattern) to make this working right.

I also suspect std::shared_ptr might be useful here.

Thanks,

Comment: A `map<string, shared_ptr<Object>>` should work

Comment: so we'll have `std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Object>> _obj;`, but how would we do a pair to insert into map? _obj.insert(std::make_pair(handle,**obj**));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would exercise caution here, in your example you're storing your objects as **Object** strictly (on the stack), since that would only allocate enough space for something of type **Object**, should you insert something that inherits from the type, it would have the part that describes the subclass sliced.

Good examples of the problem at hand:

- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/
- [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c#274636)

One way to get around the problem is to handle pointers to the objects in your **ObjectHandler** instead, the objects themselves allocted on the heap.

If I'm just misinterpreting your post, then I apologise.

But if you as you said, will store smart pointers to the object instead, making a pair should look something like this:

```
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Object>> _obj;;
std::string handle = "hello"; //Or whatever the actual handle is.
std::shared_ptr<Object> keyvalue(new Object());

objects[handle] = std::shared_ptr<Object>(keyvalue); //alternative to std::make_pair
objects.insert(std::make_pair(handle, std::shared_ptr<Object>(keyvalue))); //this also works
```

Depending on at what point you want to start handling objects with smart pointers, insertion might look like:

```
    void InsertObject(std::string handle, Object* obj){
        _obj.insert(std::make_pair(handle,std::shared_ptr<Object>(obj)));
    }

    std::string key("hi");
    InsertObject(key, new Object());
```

or alternatively just:

```
    void InsertObject(std::string handle, std::shared_ptr<Object> obj){
        _obj.insert(std::make_pair(handle, obj));
    }
```

Also note that std::map's indexing operator[] overwrites the old value if it exists, while the insert you're already using will only insert if the old one doesn't exist.

Comment: cool! thanks for detailed suggestion. i've ammended the first post with shared_ptr<Object>. Compiled, looks fine. the last step left is to figure out 'cc = oh.RetrieveObject("cat#1");' how to deal with returned shared_ptr<Object> and get object instance instead..

Comment: You can just dereference the pointer and you'll get a direct reference to the object, shared_ptr has overloaded * operator.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*

Comment: `Object obj; Dog dd; obj = *(oh.RetrieveObject(h));` but this returns type=Object. when i want to get my dog back, compiler complains about `operator=` : `dd = *(oh.RetrieveObject(h));`. will i have slicing problem you mentioned above?

Comment: Yes you would, take note that also when returning something of a supertype, you wouldn't be able to access members that are unique to a subtype without a cast to the subtype. Don't forget to make your destructor virtual either, http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-dtors.html. It's important!